# Need small storage for a django heroku web app

Tags: web-services, web-applications, heroku

I have a web app which fetches some images from web and stores it on the server. On my local server I could use the filesystem for images using the very convenient ImageField.upload_to . But since heroku does not let images be uploaded, I am not able to use the same mechanism. The number of images is around 400 ,for which I dont need more than 15 MB storage.
My question is what are the possible ways ahead for me to upload around 15 MB of data for my django heroku web app:

1. S3 - isnt 15 MB too less to get into S3. Plus I dont have a credit card and AWS does not accept debit cards.
2. Dropbox - can I somehow use dropbox as a storage service ?
3. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok since nobody answered:
I ended up doing it with S3. Used the Django app `storages` to plugin S3 as the default file storage backend. And then ImageField.upload_to would save the image on S3 bucket instead of local filesystem. 
Could create account using my Debit card on AWS and it was offering a free tier, so S3 it is.
Dropbox can probably also be used but would not integrate as seamlessly as S3.